# What is the reason for the output for this java code?

Tags: java, syntax

```
class Printer {
    static {
        System.out.println("Static block in Printer class");
    }

    public static void display(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}

public class Tester {
    public static int sampleVariable = 1;

    static {
        System.out.println("Static block in Tester class");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sampleVariable++;
        Printer p = null;
        System.out.println("In main");
        p.display("The value of sample variable is: " + sampleVariable);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Static block in Tester class; 
In main; 
Static block in Printer class; 
The value of sample variable is: 2
```

My doubts are the order in which classes are loaded. And also Even though p=null, why p.display() is working.

Comment: What exactly are you doubting?

Comment: because the `display` method is static, you could even do `Printer.display("")`

Answer (score 1):

To invoke static method you don't need instance of class, you can call it by `className.methodName`, so p.display() is working.

and order of output displayed is correct as static blocks will be loaded before members of class

```
Static block in Tester class; 
In main; 
Static block in Printer class; 
The value of sample variable is: 2
```